# Max on the partition key column seems too expensive

Tags: google-bigquery

Imagine having a table called `my_table` partitioned by a column named `importantColumn`.

I am wondering why BigQuery prices a query like this:

```
SELECT MAX(importantColumn)
FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table`
```

to be much more expensive than e.g. this one:

```
SELECT MAX(importantColumn)
FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table`
WHERE importantColumn > "2023-05-01"
```

Shouldn't BigQuery do things in such a manner that it knows which is the newest partition and charge us only for reading that one partition instead of the whole table? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the partition view, and this would you charge you less than query the whole table.

```sql
SELECT
  table_name,
  MIN(partition_id)AS min_entry,
  MAX(partition_id) AS max_entry,
  SUM(total_rows) AS total_rows,
  MAX(last_modified_time) AS last_change
FROM
  `my_project.my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
WHERE table_name="my_table"
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: need to consider empty partitions

Answer (score 1):

Implemented it in a stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE model.max_partition_datetime(
  IN datasetName STRING,
  IN tableName STRING, 
  IN dateTimeColumnName STRING,
  OUT retVal TIMESTAMP
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE maxPartitionDateString STRING;
  -- Get the maximum partition
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  '''
  SELECT
    MAX(case when partition_id != '__NULL__' then partition_id end) 
    AS max_partition_date_string
FROM
  `''' || datasetName || '''.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
WHERE table_name = "''' || tableName || '''"
  '''
  INTO maxPartitionDateString;
  -- After getting the last partition find the exact value
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  '''
  SELECT 
    max(''' || dateTimeColumnName || ''')
  FROM
    `''' || datasetName || '.' || tableName || '''`  
  WHERE 
     ''' || dateTimeColumnName || ''' >= 
     CAST(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', "''' || maxPartitionDateString || '''") AS TIMESTAMP)
  '''
  INTO retVal;
END;
```

To call:

```
DECLARE retCode TIMESTAMP;
CALL model.max_partition_datetime('my_ds', 'my_table', 'upload_timestamp', retCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second query(less expensive) seemed to be a [partition pruning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#overview). It is a part of BigQuery's mechanism to **eliminate unnecessary partitions which helps query cost lesser**.

This is an example of `prune partition` of **time-unit column-partitioned table**:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.table
WHERE transaction_date >= '2016-01-01'
```

You can also determine query costs before running the query by pruning a partitioned table, then issuing a query [dry run](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dry-run-queries) to estimate query costs.